# Delete vertices, keep faces

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces

I'm trying to delete vertices of which are sitting in the center of a line, but when I delete them the 2 faces it touches deletes with it. I want to keep those faces. What do I do?

Comment: Note that faces are 'defined' with the help of vertices, and not vice-versa

Comment: Also, please add more details, and pictures too if possible

Comment: Have you tried _dissolving_ instead of deleting (X > Dissolve Vertices)?

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a vertex, the face sticking to it also be deleted. The only way is to delete the vertex and create back the face.

Answer (score 0):

Select the loop or edges you want to delete with 'alt left mouse', hit the 'x' key on your keyboard-which should bring up the Delete Menu options, then select 'edge loop' (or whichever option you would like to delete).